# Getting multiple tourist visas at the same time

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, russia

I am an Indian citizen currently living in Stockholm Sweden for more than 2 years. I will be staying in Sweden for a year more.

I was recently planning on visiting Moscow for tourism purposes . But on checking with the Russian Embassy in Stockholm i found out that i am not eligible to apply for a Russian visa from Stockholm and can do this only from India.

Now I am planning to visit India soon (will be there for a week) and will most probably get a visa from there for my visit in April for (3-4 days). But I also plan to visit Moscow again in May or June for a few more days.

Since I wont be able to visit India again in this time for a new visa. Is it possible for me to get visas for both these trips at the same time when I am in India. I can of course apply two times, pay the fee and submit the documents separately for both visas.

Please let me know if this is possible since there is no way for me to get a visa for Russia once I am in Sweden.

Answer (score 4):

Russia has such a tight policy about where you can get visas from.

You can easily apply for a multi-entry visa, with sufficient proofs that you would like to visit there more than one time. Multi-entry visas are usually valid for 3 months or more, so it should be OK for your case.

Embassies of other countries do not usually care about what other usable visas you have. I have multi-entry visas for Malaysia in my passport, a double-entry Indian visa, both still valid, and I'm going to Nepal tomorrow. I'm almost sure I won't face any issues.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I dont think Russia supports the concept of multiple entry visa for Indian nationalist. I have searched multiple locations. The only way to get a double entry visa is when you leave the country to visit someplace and will get back which is not my case.

Comment: Russia is rather different country IMO when it comes to Visa. They have their own reasoning though. I'm sure you can convince the consulate that you plan to come to the country twice and going to India again is expensive, takes time and impractical.

Comment: @KaranveerSinghSodhi Yes, [in 2011 Russia and India signed a bilateral visa agreement](http://www.thehindu.com/news/international/simplified-russian-visa-rules-for-indians/article2565513.ece) and Indian citizens can now [get multiple entry visas to Russia with stays of up to 90 days in every 180 days](http://rusembindia.com/visas-consular-services-en/visa-information). Because this is specific to India, the Russian consulates in Sweden won't know about it and would have difficulty to process your application.